# Need help cycling through a webpage's links on selenium

Tags: html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I want to cycle through some links in [this](http://www.nse.com.ng/market-data/trading-statistics/equities) webpage, but I'm not sure how to go about it. The section I want to get the links from is this one:

[image]

Which is basically the footer. So for a brief description of what I'm trying to do, I want to scrape all of the links for the securities listed in the table and then cycle through the footer so I can change pages and scrape the links off of those as well:

[image]

So currently this is page 1 and I can scrape what I want, but I don't know how to proceed to page two and continue the process. I'll show you why in a second:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
from requests import get

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.nse.com.ng/market-data/trading-statistics/equities")

time.sleep(30)

html = driver.page_source
soup = bs(html,"html.parser")
driver.close()
```

Above is my code. Now if I wanted to find the footer section I'd do this:

`foot = soup.find("ul",class_="pagination no-top-pad").find_all("a")`

And it truly returns the list of footer/pages:

[image]

However, as you can see, it doesn't really use links. There's a simple `"#"` symbol under the `href` for each page. So I can't just get the links and cycle through them. This is my problem. How do you suggest I move from page 1 to page 2 and so on? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The page is loading the data from external URL via JavaScript, you can use this example to load the pages into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


url = 'http://www.nse.com.ng/REST/api/statistics/equities/?market=&sector=&orderby=&pageSize=10&pageNo={page}'

for page in range(0, 10):
    df = pd.read_json(url.format(page=page))
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...

   $id   Id      Symbol  ...      Market              Sector        Company2
0    1  123        JULI  ...        ASeM            SERVICES      JULI [MRF]
1    2   96      LASACO  ...  Main Board  FINANCIAL SERVICES         LASACO 
2    3  150    LAWUNION  ...  Main Board  FINANCIAL SERVICES  LAWUNION [DIP]
3    4  116  LEARNAFRCA  ...  Main Board            SERVICES     LEARNAFRCA 
4    5   92  LINKASSURE  ...  Main Board  FINANCIAL SERVICES     LINKASSURE 
5    6   48   LIVESTOCK  ...  Main Board         AGRICULTURE      LIVESTOCK 
6    7  106     MANSARD  ...  Main Board  FINANCIAL SERVICES        MANSARD 
7    8  141    MAYBAKER  ...  Main Board          HEALTHCARE       MAYBAKER 
8    9   23    MBENEFIT  ...  Main Board  FINANCIAL SERVICES       MBENEFIT 
9   10   47   MCNICHOLS  ...        ASeM      CONSUMER GOODS      MCNICHOLS 

[10 rows x 16 columns]
   $id   Id      Symbol  ...         Market             Sector          Company2
0    1  153  MEDVIEWAIR  ...     Main Board           SERVICES  MEDVIEWAIR [BMF]
1    2  146       MEYER  ...     Main Board   INDUSTRIAL GOODS            MEYER 
2    3   89       MOBIL  ...     Main Board        OIL AND GAS            MOBIL 
3    4   98     MORISON  ...     Main Board         HEALTHCARE          MORISON 
4    5   18         MRS  ...     Main Board        OIL AND GAS              MRS 
5    6  162        MTNN  ...  Premium Board                ICT             MTNN 
6    7  148   MULTITREX  ...     Main Board     CONSUMER GOODS   MULTITREX [BMR]
7    8   49  MULTIVERSE  ...     Main Board  NATURAL RESOURCES       MULTIVERSE 
8    9  143       NAHCO  ...     Main Board           SERVICES            NAHCO 
9   10  158      NASCON  ...     Main Board     CONSUMER GOODS           NASCON 

[10 rows x 16 columns]


...
```